# How to run PowerShell script in C# from relative path?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script from my C# application.  I know how to do so with an absolute path:

```
    using (PowerShell pshell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        pshell.AddScript( @"C:\Path\To\Webapp\psScript.ps1" );
        pshell.Invoke();
    }
```

What I don't know how to do is use a relative path.  My `psScript.ps1` is located in the same directory as my Visual Studio project, and I'd like to use a relative path (such as `./psScript.ps1`), so that when I publish/export my project to different computers, the path to the script doesn't become invalidated

Sooo, how do I use a relative path in the PowerShell.AddScript() method?  Any help would be appreciated!

I looked here but this doesn't answer my question: 
[PowerShell: Run command from script's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724290/powershell-run-command-from-scripts-directory)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
using (PowerShell pshell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        string path=System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        pshell.AddScript( path+"\\psScript.ps1" );
        pshell.Invoke();
    }
```

This path is always relative to the root folder of your project.

Comment: Is this the same as the `$(ProjectDir)` directory?  I just printed the result of the `path` string in your above example and it was a very different location.  Thank you, nonetheless.  This puts me a lot closer to finding the solution than I was before

Comment: `path` in your case is the path of the executable not of the project root. It is same as `pshell.AddScript( "psScript.ps1" );`

Answer (score 3):

Add your script to project and set `Copy to output directory` property to `Copy always` or `Copy id newer`