# Defining Variable for Powershell script in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to run a ps script with this code

```
 private void materialButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (PowerShell pshell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            pshell.AddCommand("Zuordnung.ps1");
            pshell.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820943/how-to-run-powershell-script-in-c-sharp-from-relative-path) in a c# winforms app

the ps script includes:

```
$Destination = "\\path1\"
Get-ChildItem "\\path2" | ForEach-Object {
    $Tail = ($_.BaseName -split '_')[-2]
    $Filter = "*_{0}" -f $Tail
    $DestDir = Get-ChildItem $Destination -Filter $Filter -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName -First 1
    if ($DestDir) {
        Copy-Item $_.FullName $DestDir -Force
    } else {
        "No Directory was found that matched the Filter {0} in Directory {1}" -f $Filter, $Destination | Write-Host
    }
```

Path1 and Path2 are supposed to be pulled off textboxes

```
pshell.AddParameter("Path1", "C:\somepath")
```

is looking good but im trying to set them dynamic e.g.

```
pshell.AddParameter(@"$Destination", {textbox1.text}
```

textbox1.text gets its value from a folder browser dialog

im also trying

```
 SessionState.PSVariable.Set("source", {guna2TextBox4.Text});
SessionState.PSVariable.Set("$source", {guna2TextBox4.Text});
SessionState.PSVariable.Set($@"source", {guna2TextBox4.Text});
```

Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [`pshell.AddParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addparameters?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.2#addparameter). Also I think you want `AddCommand` not `AddScript`

Comment: no, i dont get how to assign a certain value to the ps variables

Comment: `pshell.AddParameter("Path1", "C:\somepath")`

Comment: ive updated the question, im trying to set textbox.text string as $destination

Comment: `pshell.AddParameter("Destination", textbox1.text);` you don't need the `$`

Comment: this works for me thanks alot

Comment: You should accept the duplicate using the button I think you have