# PowerShell: run command line application from within powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line-interface

Suppose I have a Windows commandline application (`abc.exe`) in: `C:\test` folder.
I've put my powershell script file in the same location too.

by using this command I set the current location to the location where my script is launched from:

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot
```

I need to run `abc.exe` from within my script so that by pressing Control+C in the execution window of my script, it terminates `abc.exe` too.

If I use this syntax: `C:\test\abc.exe` in my script, everything is as what I want. but the problem is that I don't want to hard code the location of `abc.exe` in my script since user may change it.(**note:** `abc.exe` will always be in the same location as my script)

If I just use: `abc.exe` I will get:

```
& : The term 'abc.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

What should I do?

Update: In windows Batch scripting, pressing Control+C in such situation will easily terminates both the execution of script and commandline application

Comment: Checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724290/powershell-run-command-from-scripts-directory. Also note, use ".\abc.exe" to reference the command in the current directory.

Comment: I read that but couldn't figure out what to do

Comment: What part couldn't you figure out?

Comment: The exact code that I should use

Comment: & $PSScriptRoot\abc.exe

Comment: Check out: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx#The_Call_Operator_amp

Comment: `& "$PSScriptRoot\abc.exe"` or, if you're already at $PSScriptRoot, then just `.\abc.exe`.

Comment: the problem is Control+C will terminate the script not the abc.exe

Comment: Yes, that's how batch files work, too.  Remember seeing `^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?` before?  If your command line program doesn't trap Ctrl + C itself then you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Did your try this ...

```
Start-Process -PSPath "C:\test\abc.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\test" -NoNewWindow
```

Second suggestion:

```
Start-Process -PSPath "C:\test\abc.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\test" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Comment: I want to have the results and interactions of abc.exe from within my script (like in batch scripts) not opening a completely separate window for running abc.exe

Comment: See second suggestion at Answer.