# Automate creation of symbolic links on Windows bash

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux, symlink, pywin32

I'm trying to make a script that will do some directory management. The final script will run on **Windows** and will preferably be written in **python**. At one point in the script I need to automate the creation of multiple **symbolic links** between multiple folders. The script itself runs without administrator permissions from a bash terminal (Git Bash). Windows is not in developer mode.

The perfect solution would be to have a list of tuples (link, source) and create the corresponding symbolic links all at once, while having to press "Yes" for administrator rights only once.

I already did some research:

- How to create a symlink between directories from inside an elevated cmd: [Git Bash shell fails to create symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641864/git-bash-shell-fails-to-create-symbolic-links)

  `mklink /D link source_directory`
- How to run a command in cmd as an administrator from inside bash: [Launch Elevated CMD.exe from Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267766/launch-elevated-cmd-exe-from-powershell)

  `powershell 'start cmd -v runAs -Args /k, [comma-separated-args]'`
- How to set the working directory after launching the powershell command as an administrator (Otherwise it launches a terminal from inside C:\Windows\System32\): [PowerShell: Run command from script's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724290/powershell-run-command-from-scripts-directory)

  `powershell 'start cmd -v runAs -Args /k, cd, $pwd, "&", [comma-separated-args]'`

Let's say I want to create a symbolic link **in my current working directory to a relative directory**. I tried 2 ways:

1. When I combine all of the above points and execute the following command from the Git Bash terminal:

   `powershell 'start cmd -v runAs -Args /k, cd, $pwd, "&", mklink, /D, \"link_to_utils\", \"common\utils\"'`

   A new terminal opens up (after agreeing for admin rights). But it resulted in a new symlink being created in the **root of C:\** .
2. When I execute this:

   `powershell 'start cmd -v runAs -Args /k, cd, $pwd`

   A new terminal opens up (after agreeing for admin rights). I can now run this command:

   `mklink /D "link_to_utils" "common\utils"`

   The link is created in the current working directory, as I wanted.

So my questions are:

a) How can I make option 1 work in bash?

b) Why is it actually creating the symlink in C:\?

c) Is there a way to pipe a command into the opened elevated cmd terminal (to make option 2 work)?

Note: I have been trying to find a solution using python and the win32api (pywin32). But that resulted in a bunch of command prompts opening up for each symlink that needs to be created. Also there is barely any documentation regarding pywin32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```bash
powershell 'Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd /k, " cd `"$PWD`" & mklink /D `"link_to_utils`" `"common\utils`" "'
```

- Since it is PowerShell that interprets that verbatim content of the command line being passed, *its* syntax rules must be followed, meaning that a `"..."` (double-quoted) string is required for expansion (string interpolation) of the automatic `$PWD` variable to occur, and that *embedded* `"` characters inside that string must be escaped as `` `" `` (`""` would work too).
- The pass-through command line *for `cmd.exe`* is passed as a *single* string argument, for conceptual clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer is showing a solution using PowerShell, don't overlook that one can use the `New-Item` PowerShell command to create Symbolic Links from an elevated context.

Microsoft PowerShell Help for New-Item: [Example 7: Create a symbolic link to a file or folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-5.1&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp#example-7-create-a-symbolic-link-to-a-file-or-folder).

```
$link = New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path .\link -Target .\Notice.txt
$link | Select-Object LinkType, Target

LinkType     Target
--------     ------
SymbolicLink {.\Notice.txt}
```